# Flutter - The const widget still rebuild when its parent rebuild

Tags: flutter

I have a question about when and how a const widget will rebuild.

For example, I have a demo project like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const child = ChildWidget();
    return OrientationBuilder(
      builder: (context, orientation) {
        debugPrint('$orientation');
        final isPortrait = orientation == Orientation.portrait;
        return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: isPortrait
              ? Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: const [
                      SizedBox(height: 200, child: child),
                      Text('Bellow text'),
                    ])
              : child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChildWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChildWidget> createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _counter += 1;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue, child: Center(child: Text('$_counter'))),
    );
  }
}
```

As you see, I have a const ChildWidget.
`const child = ChildWidget();`

When I rotate the device, it will trigger the `builder` function of the OrientationBuilder and return a new Container. But my question is why the `child` widget is rebuilt again while it is a const.

The reason why I want the `child` widget is not rebuilt is that I don't want the counter Text to reset to 0 each time I rotate the device.

Please advice.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

While the variable and object assigned are constant, the framework will still call the `build`  method on the child widgets. So the actual `ChildWidget` class is not recreated, but the `build` *will* be called.

This is not really a problem. Flutter is really optimized for rebuilding Widgets. If the data has not changed, the actual cost of rebuilding is negligible.

Comment: Thank you, but how about I want to keep the elements of the ```child``` widget unchanged? I edited the question, please check again.

Comment: right, you changed the `ChildWidget` to a` StateFullWidget` now in your question.  You need to read about [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) for this. Basically, extract the `_counter` to a shared state.